# NLTK - Get and Simplify List of Tags

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I'm using the Brown Corpus. I want some way to print out all the possible tags and their names (not just tag abbreviations). There are also quite a few tags, is there a way to 'simplify' the tags? By simplify I mean combine two extremely similar tags into one and re-tag the merged words with the other tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's somehow discussed previously in:

- [Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)
- [Simplifying the French POS Tag Set with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513185/simplifying-the-french-pos-tag-set-with-nltk)
- https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/turn-penn-treebank-into-simpler-pos-tags

The POS tag output from `nltk.pos_tag` are PennTreeBank tagset, https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html, see [What are all possible pos tags of NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388831/what-are-all-possible-pos-tags-of-nltk)

There are several approach but **the simplest one might be to use only the first 2 characters of the POS as the main set of POS tags**. This is because the first two characters in the POS tag represents the broad classes of POS in Penn Tree Bank tagset.

For instance `NNS` means plural noun, and `NNP` means proper noun and the `NN` tag subsumes all of it by representing the generic noun.

Here's a code example:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> x = defaultdict(list)
>>> for word,pos in brown.tagged_words()[1:100]:
...     x[pos].append(word)
... 
>>> x
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'DTI': [u'any'], u'BEN': [u'been'], u'VBD': [u'said', u'produced', u'took', u'said'], u'NP$': [u"Atlanta's"], u'NN-TL': [u'County', u'Jury', u'City', u'Committee', u'City', u'Court', u'Judge', u'Mayor-nominate'], u'VBN': [u'conducted', u'charged', u'won'], u"''": [u"''", u"''", u"''"], u'WDT': [u'which', u'which', u'which'], u'JJ': [u'recent', u'over-all', u'possible', u'hard-fought'], u'VBZ': [u'deserves'], u'NN': [u'investigation', u'primary', u'election', u'evidence', u'place', u'jury', u'term-end', u'charge', u'election', u'praise', u'manner', u'election', u'term', u'jury', u'primary'], u',': [u',', u','], u'.': [u'.', u'.'], u'TO': [u'to'], u'NP': [u'September-October', u'Durwood', u'Pye', u'Ivan'], u'BEDZ': [u'was', u'was'], u'NR': [u'Friday'], u'NNS': [u'irregularities', u'presentments', u'thanks', u'reports', u'irregularities'], u'``': [u'``', u'``', u'``'], u'CC': [u'and'], u'RBR': [u'further'], u'AT': [u'an', u'no', u'The', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'The', u'the'], u'IN': [u'of', u'in', u'of', u'of', u'for', u'in', u'by', u'of', u'in', u'by'], u'CS': [u'that', u'that'], u'NP-TL': [u'Fulton', u'Atlanta', u'Fulton'], u'HVD': [u'had', u'had'], u'IN-TL': [u'of'], u'VB': [u'investigate'], u'JJ-TL': [u'Grand', u'Executive', u'Superior']})
>>> len(x)
29
```

The shorten version looks like this:

```
>>> x = defaultdict(list)
>>> for word,pos in brown.tagged_words()[1:100]:
...     x[pos[:2]].append(word)
... 
>>> x
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'BE': [u'was', u'been', u'was'], u'VB': [u'said', u'produced', u'took', u'said', u'deserves', u'conducted', u'charged', u'investigate', u'won'], u'WD': [u'which', u'which', u'which'], u'RB': [u'further'], u'NN': [u'County', u'Jury', u'investigation', u'primary', u'election', u'evidence', u'irregularities', u'place', u'jury', u'term-end', u'presentments', u'City', u'Committee', u'charge', u'election', u'praise', u'thanks', u'City', u'manner', u'election', u'term', u'jury', u'Court', u'Judge', u'reports', u'irregularities', u'primary', u'Mayor-nominate'], u'TO': [u'to'], u'CC': [u'and'], u'HV': [u'had', u'had'], u'``': [u'``', u'``', u'``'], u',': [u',', u','], u'.': [u'.', u'.'], u"''": [u"''", u"''", u"''"], u'CS': [u'that', u'that'], u'AT': [u'an', u'no', u'The', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'The', u'the'], u'JJ': [u'Grand', u'recent', u'Executive', u'over-all', u'Superior', u'possible', u'hard-fought'], u'IN': [u'of', u'in', u'of', u'of', u'of', u'for', u'in', u'by', u'of', u'in', u'by'], u'NP': [u'Fulton', u"Atlanta's", u'Atlanta', u'September-October', u'Fulton', u'Durwood', u'Pye', u'Ivan'], u'NR': [u'Friday'], u'DT': [u'any']})
>>> len(x)
19
```

**Another solution is to use the universal postags**, see http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

```
>>> x = defaultdict(list)
>>> for word,pos in brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal')[1:100]:
...     x[pos].append(word)
... 
>>> x
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'ADV': [u'further'], u'NOUN': [u'Fulton', u'County', u'Jury', u'Friday', u'investigation', u"Atlanta's", u'primary', u'election', u'evidence', u'irregularities', u'place', u'jury', u'term-end', u'presentments', u'City', u'Committee', u'charge', u'election', u'praise', u'thanks', u'City', u'Atlanta', u'manner', u'election', u'September-October', u'term', u'jury', u'Fulton', u'Court', u'Judge', u'Durwood', u'Pye', u'reports', u'irregularities', u'primary', u'Mayor-nominate', u'Ivan'], u'ADP': [u'of', u'that', u'in', u'that', u'of', u'of', u'of', u'for', u'in', u'by', u'of', u'in', u'by'], u'DET': [u'an', u'no', u'any', u'The', u'the', u'which', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'the', u'which', u'the', u'The', u'the', u'which'], u'.': [u'``', u"''", u'.', u',', u',', u'``', u"''", u'.', u'``', u"''"], u'PRT': [u'to'], u'VERB': [u'said', u'produced', u'took', u'said', u'had', u'deserves', u'was', u'conducted', u'had', u'been', u'charged', u'investigate', u'was', u'won'], u'CONJ': [u'and'], u'ADJ': [u'Grand', u'recent', u'Executive', u'over-all', u'Superior', u'possible', u'hard-fought']})
>>> len(x)
9
```

Comment: I printed out the total number of 'tags' in the brown corpus, and it gave me 472. I'm assuming this is because there are a number of tag combinations? Such as NP+HVZ-NC? That means that the word in question is possibly either of the two tags? When shortening these tags by pos[:2] it obviously cuts off tags such as "FW-AT+NP-TL" to just FW. That's an absurdly specific tag anyhow. I was really looking for a happy medium between Universal and Brown tagsets. Using [:2] I get a total of 49 which is a great number, I think. Even though there are some weird tags like ")-"

Comment: Using a `defaultdict` with `set` is much more efficient here

Answer (score 2):

Many of the tagsets in the NLTK's corpora come with predefined mappings to a simplified, "universal" tagset. In addition to being more convenient for many purposes, the simplified tagset allows a degree of compatibility between different corpora that allow remapping to the universal tagset.

For the brown corpus, you can simply fetch tagged words or sents like this:

```
brown.tagged_words(tagset="universal")
```

For example:

```
>>> print(brown.tagged_words()[:10])
[('The', 'DET'), ('Fulton', 'NOUN'), ('County', 'NOUN'), ('Grand', 'ADJ'), ('Jury', 'NOUN'),
('said', 'VERB'), ('Friday', 'NOUN'), ('an', 'DET'), ('investigation', 'NOUN'), 
('of', 'ADP')]
```

To see the definitions of the original, complex tags in the Brown corpus, use
`nltk.help.upenn_tagset()` (as mentioned also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15389153/699305) answer, linked by Alvas). You can get the whole list by calling it without arguments, or pass an argument (a regexp) to get only the matching tag(s). The results include a brief definition and examples.

```
>>> nltk.help.brown_tagset("DT.*")
DT: determiner/pronoun, singular
    this each another that 'nother
DT$: determiner/pronoun, singular, genitive
    another's
DT+BEZ: determiner/pronoun + verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    that's
DT+MD: determiner/pronoun + modal auxillary
    that'll this'll
...
```