# Select only 'NN' and 'VB' words from NTLK pos_tag

Tags: python, string, nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

I need to print only 'NN' and 'VB' words from an entered sentence.

```
import nltk
import re
import time

var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")


exampleArray = [var]


def processLanguage():
    try:
        for item in exampleArray:
            tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(item)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
            print tagged

            time.sleep(555)


    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

processLanguage()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about changing

```
    print tagged
```

to

```
    print [(word, tag) for word, tag in tagged if tag in ('NN', 'VB')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the first 2 characters of the POS tag, see [NLTK - Get and Simplify List of Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791194/nltk-get-and-simplify-list-of-tags/30793767#30793767)

```
nn_vb_tagged = [(word,tag) for word, tag in tagged 
                if tag.startswith('NN') or tag.startswith('VB')]
```

Comment: `str.startswith` also accepts a tuple: `tag.startswith(('NN', 'VB'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
example = "This is a sample sentence, showing off the stop words filtration.!"
word_tokens = word_tokenize(example)
pos = nltk.pos_tag(word_tokens)
selective_pos = ['NN','VB']
selective_pos_words = []
for word,tag in pos:
     if tag in selective_pos:
         selective_pos_words.append((word,tag))
print(selective_pos_words)
```

By adding your selective parts of speech in the list "selective_pos", you can select any of your preferable word.