# Why Python NLTK does not tag correctly in spanish language?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I have the following code:

```
import nltk

sent='El gato está bajo la mesa de cristal.'
nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent), lang='spa')
```

But the output is not accurate at all:

```
[('El', 'NNP'),
 ('gato', 'NN'),
 ('está', 'NN'),
 ('bajo', 'NN'),
 ('la', 'FW'),
 ('mesa', 'FW'),
 ('de', 'FW'),
 ('cristal', 'NN'),
 ('.', '.')]
```

For instance, `es` should be categorized as a verb.

If I try the same using English phrase:

```
import nltk

sent='The cat is under the cristal table.'
nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent), lang='spa')
```

It works ok:

```
[('The', 'DT'),
 ('cat', 'NN'),
 ('is', 'VBZ'),
 ('under', 'IN'),
 ('the', 'DT'),
 ('cristal', 'NN'),
 ('table', 'NN'),
 ('.', '.')]
```

Note that I've downloaded all the nltk resources. Could you tell me what I am missing here so the word tagging is not working in the Spanish language?

Comment: There's no spanish model in NLTK for POS tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [the following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478073/1709738)

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
jar = 'D:/Downloads/stanford-postagger-full-2018-10-16/stanford-postagger-3.9.2.jar'
model = 'D:/Downloads/stanford-postagger-full-2018-10-16/models/spanish.tagger'

import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

pos_tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model, jar, encoding='utf8' )
pos_tagger.tag('El gato está bajo la mesa de cristal'.split())
```

Result:

```
[('El', 'da0000'),
 ('gato', 'nc0s000'),
 ('está', 'vmip000'),
 ('bajo', 'sp000'),
 ('la', 'da0000'),
 ('mesa', 'nc0s000'),
 ('de', 'sp000'),
 ('cristal', 'nc0s000')]
```

Comment: How do you interpret the POS codings?  Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import stanfordnlp
MODELS_DIR = '.'
stanfordnlp.download('es', MODELS_DIR) # Download the Spanish models
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,pos', models_dir=MODELS_DIR, treebank='es_ancora', use_gpu=True, pos_batch_size=3000) # Build the pipeline, specify part-of-speech processor's batch size
doc = nlp("Tu frse en español.") # Run the pipeline on input text
doc.sentences[0].print_tokens() # Look at the result
```