# AttributeError: type object 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' has no attribute 'get_extension'

Tags: python, conda, spacy

I am trying to use the french tokenizer and lemmatizer (LefffLemmatizer) of Spacy. I am using Python 3.6 in Conda environment.

However when I am trying to install the french version `python -m spacy download fr`, I have an error code `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cymem'`. So, I did a check via `pip list` (to see if I had it) and I do. I did a `conda update --all` just to be sure the issue was not comming from my setting.

I was thinking I could bypass this by using the model from spacy. 
My current code is then trying to bypass it :

```
import spacy
from spacy import fr
from spacy.fr import French

nlp = French()
tokenizer = nlp.Defaults.create_tokenizer(nlp)

from spacy_lefff import LefffLemmatizer, POSTagger

pos = POSTagger()
french_lemmatizer = LefffLemmatizer(after_melt=True, default=True)
nlp.add_pipe(pos, name='pos', after='parser')
nlp.add_pipe(french_lemmatizer, name='lefff', after='pos')
doc = nlp("Apple cherche a acheter une startup anglaise pour 1 milliard de dollard")
for d in doc:
    print(d.text, d.pos_, d._.melt_tagger, d._.lefff_lemma, d.tag_, d.lemma_)
```

This is not working either. I have the next error happening.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-6802b928c839> in <module>()
----> 3 pos = POSTagger()
...
--> 109         if not tk.get_extension(self.name):
...
AttributeError: type object 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' has no attribute 'get_extension'
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks for anyone who could help me.

Bianca

Comment: I think this isn't the correct way to load the French nlp model. Could you try this one: `nlp = spacy.load('fr')`?

Comment: I tried it... and it still does not work. Right now, if I am trying to import spacy I have
`----> 3 import spacy
---> 12 from . import pipeline
...
----> 4 from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cymem'`

Comment: Try to uninstall spacy using `pip uninstall spacy`. Then, try install it via conda by running this `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`

Comment: Thanks! (you are my hero.) I am now able to run spacy. However, i still have error running when i am trying to import 'Spacy Leffff" `from spacy_lefff import LefffLemmatizer, POSTagger ----> 1 from .lefff import LefffLemmatizer ----> 7 from spacy.tokens import Token ImportError: cannot import name 'Token'`.

Comment: what is the version of `spacy_lefff` that you're using?

Comment: I am using version 0.3.6

Comment: It doesn't show that error on my machine.. it shows another error though :)

Comment: What can I do from there? I am about to call it a quit. It makes a week I am trying to tag and lemmatize one corpus

Comment: Have you followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478073/5612363)?

Comment: I ended up uninstalling completly anaconda and installing it back. And it fixed the issue. Something went probably wrong when I updated Conda.

Comment: Nice hearing that everything worked out eventually